# How to calculate the amount spent for the last month in SQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table transaction_details:

| transaction_id | customer_id | item_id | item_number | transaction_dttm |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7765 | 1 | 23 | 1 | 2022-01-15 |
| 1254 | 2 | 12 | 4 | 2022-02-03 |
| 3332 | 3 | 56 | 2 | 2022-02-15 |
| 7658 | 1 | 43 | 1 | 2022-03-01 |
| 7231 | 4 | 56 | 1 | 2022-01-15 |
| 7231 | 2 | 23 | 2 | 2022-01-29 |

I need to form a table of the following type customer_aggr:

| customer_id | amount_spent_lm | top_item_lm |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 700 | glasses |
| 2 | 20000 | notebook |
| 3 | 100 | cup |

When calculating, it is necessary to take into account the current price at the time of the transaction (dict_item_prices). Customers who have not made purchases in the last month are not included in the final table. he last month is defined as the last 30 days at the time of the report creation.

There is also a table dict_item_prices:

| item_id | item_name | item_price | valid_from_dt | valid_to_dt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | phone 1 | 1000 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-12-31 |
| 12 | notebook | 5000 | 2022-01-02 | 2022-12-31 |
| 56 | cup | 50 | 2022-01-02 | 2022-12-31 |
| 43 | glasses | 700 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-12-31 |

Comment: Recommend you read up on [Date/Time Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html). Of particular use is `age()` which you can use to filter data from `transaction_details` (WHERE age(transaction_dttm) <= 30 DAYS). To look up price customer paid, you'll want [BETWEEN operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html).

Comment: Correction. Should be WHERE age(transaction_dttm) <= interval '30 DAYS'

Comment: I studied what you suggested to me, I still can't do it(